# Is there a plugin for the terminal which allow to detect and open files?

Tags: command-line, compiling, make, doxygen

I'm looking for a terminal plugin/extension that would allow me to detect files path in terminal output and open them in a text editor by clicking on them. The perfect solution would open the file at the given line.

```
/home/dell/pcl/2d/include/pcl/2d/impl/keypoint.hpp:233: warning: no uniquely matching class member found for void pcl::keypoint::imageElementMultiply(ImageType &output, ImageType &input1, ImageType &input2)
```

In the example above I would be able to click on `/home/dell/pcl/2d/include/pcl/2d/impl/keypoint.hpp:233` and I would open the file with Gedit (or whatever) at line 233.

Comment: what's wrong with `cd` and `nano` ?

Comment: When you just have to change 2/3 characters in a file for X files at a given line; copy/paste and `nano` is not productive.

Comment: If you are more interested in batch replacing the same 2/3 characters in X files then your problem has several (automated) solutions. If it's your case, please open a new question detailing the pattern to look for and the type of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I though, I may need such option myself. AFAIK, `gnome-terminal` does not support plug-ins.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, gnome-terminal 3.6.2. I didn't test for enough time, expect bugs.

1. Download source & build dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal
   apt-get source gnome-terminal
   ```
2. Add support for paths

   `src/terminal-screen.h`, add `FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE` enum type for file paths

   ```
   typedef enum {
     FLAVOR_AS_IS,
     FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_HTTP,
     FLAVOR_VOIP_CALL,
     FLAVOR_EMAIL,
     FLAVOR_LP,
     FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE
   } TerminalURLFlavour;
   ```

   `src/terminal-screen.c`, add path regex (it's not perfect, may need some tuning)

   ```
   static const TerminalRegexPattern url_regex_patterns[] = {
     { SCHEME "//(?:" USERPASS "\\@)?" HOST PORT URLPATH, FLAVOR_AS_IS, G_REGEX_CASELESS },
     { "(?:www|ftp)" HOSTCHARS_CLASS "*\\." HOST PORT URLPATH , FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_HTTP, G_REGEX_CASELESS  },
     { "(?:callto:|h323:|sip:)" USERCHARS_CLASS "[" USERCHARS ".]*(?:" PORT "/[a-z0-9]+)?\\@" HOST, FLAVOR_VOIP_CALL, G_REGEX_CASELESS  },
     { "(?:mailto:)?" USERCHARS_CLASS "[" USERCHARS ".]*\\@" HOSTCHARS_CLASS "+\\." HOST, FLAVOR_EMAIL, G_REGEX_CASELESS  },
     { "(?:news:|man:|info:)[[:alnum:]\\Q^_{|}~!\"#$%&'()*+,./;:=?`\\E]+", FLAVOR_AS_IS, G_REGEX_CASELESS  },
     { "(?:lp: #)[[:digit:]]+", FLAVOR_LP, G_REGEX_CASELESS  },
     { "((~/)|(\\.\\./)|(\\./)|(/))+[^\\n\\t\\r\\v\\0 !$`&*()+:]+[^\\n\\t\\r\\v\\0 !$`&*()+:?.,;\"'\\]\\[<>#{}(]", FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE, G_REGEX_CASELESS },
   };
   ```

   `src/terminal-util.c`, compose correct URL by adding `file://` prefix

   ```
     switch (flavor)
       {
       case FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_HTTP:
         uri = g_strdup_printf ("http://%s", orig_url);
         break;
       case FLAVOR_EMAIL:
         if (g_ascii_strncasecmp ("mailto:", orig_url, 7) != 0)
       uri = g_strdup_printf ("mailto:%s", orig_url);
         else
       uri = g_strdup (orig_url);
         break;
       case FLAVOR_VOIP_CALL:
       case FLAVOR_AS_IS:
         uri = g_strdup (orig_url);
         break;
       case FLAVOR_LP:
         uri = terminal_util_get_lp_url (orig_url);
         break;
       case FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE:
         uri = g_strdup_printf ("file://%s", orig_url);
         break;    
       default:
         uri = NULL;
         g_assert_not_reached ();
       }
   ```

   `src/terminal-window.c`, resolve `~` and relative paths (`./` & `../`)

   ```
   static void
   popup_open_url_callback (GtkAction *action,
                            TerminalWindow *window)
   {
     TerminalWindowPrivate *priv = window->priv;
     TerminalScreenPopupInfo *info = priv->popup_info;

     if (info == NULL)
       return;

     if (info->flavour==FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE){
       if (info->string[0]=='~') {
         char* current_dir_full=terminal_util_resolve_relative_path (g_get_home_dir(), &(info->string)[2]);
         terminal_util_open_url (GTK_WIDGET (window), current_dir_full, info->flavour,
                               gtk_get_current_event_time ());
       } else {
         char* current_dir=terminal_screen_get_current_dir_with_fallback (info->screen);
         char* current_dir_full=terminal_util_resolve_relative_path (current_dir, info->string);
         terminal_util_open_url (GTK_WIDGET (window), current_dir_full, info->flavour,
                               gtk_get_current_event_time ());
       }
     }
     else {
       terminal_util_open_url (GTK_WIDGET (window), info->string, info->flavour,
                             gtk_get_current_event_time ());
     }
   }
   ```

   ...

   ```
     show_link = info->string != NULL && (info->flavour == FLAVOR_AS_IS ||
                                          info->flavour == FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_HTTP ||
                                          info->flavour == FLAVOR_LP ||
                                          info->flavour == FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE );
   ```

   ...

   ```
   static gboolean
   screen_match_clicked_cb (TerminalScreen *screen,
                            const char *match,
                            int flavour,
                            guint state,
                            TerminalWindow *window)
   {
     TerminalWindowPrivate *priv = window->priv;

     if (screen != priv->active_screen)
       return FALSE;

     gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET (screen));

     if (flavour==FLAVOR_DEFAULT_TO_FILE){
       if (match[0]=='~') {
         char* current_dir_full=terminal_util_resolve_relative_path (g_get_home_dir(), &(match)[2]);
         terminal_util_open_url (GTK_WIDGET (window), current_dir_full, flavour,
                               gtk_get_current_event_time ());
       } else {
         char* current_dir=terminal_screen_get_current_dir_with_fallback (screen);
         char* current_dir_full=terminal_util_resolve_relative_path (current_dir, match);
         terminal_util_open_url (GTK_WIDGET (window), current_dir_full, flavour,
                               gtk_get_current_event_time ());
       }
     }
     else {
       terminal_util_open_url (GTK_WIDGET (window), match, flavour,
                               gtk_get_current_event_time ());
     }

     return TRUE;
   }
   ```
3. Build & install

   ```
   cd gnome-terminal-3.6.2/
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

Comment: 3. Build & install: `./configure` first :)
Thanks a lot for the work invovled, it works great!

Answer (score 2):

Only links can be opened from a terminal (right-click -> Open Link), basically you'd need to prefix your file path with the full URI:

```
/home/dell/pcl/2d/include/pcl/2d/impl/keypoint.hpp
```

becoming (just add the `file://` prefix):

```
file:///home/dell/pcl/2d/include/pcl/2d/impl/keypoint.hpp
```

[image]

Note: This command will give you the absolute path URI to a file:

```
echo file://$(readlink -f <your file>)
```

Personally `gedit /home/dell/pcl/2d/include/pcl/2d/impl/keypoint.hpp` is probably the best option.

Comment: I just found a little bit better:
`gedit +233 /home/dell/pcl/2d/include/pcl/2d/impl/keypoint.hpp`

I would like an integrated solution to avoid copy/paste etc.

Comment: I don't think that what you're requesting is actually supported in a terminal. As I said only plain URI are click-able.

Comment: @VictorL as Sylavain told you this is a ridiculously complex way. If you want to change specific characters on specific lines, you should never need to actually open the file in an editor. Please post a new question asking how to do what you actually need to do. What you describe is trivial to automate in a way that you can process thousands of files in just a couple of seconds.

Comment: The topic is related to `compiling` & `doxygen`. I mostly need to open .hpp files and correct tags etc. for a huge documentation. Human reading of surrounding code + intervention is irreplaceable here.