# Terminal : open path with middle-click/context menu?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I spend a lot of time copying the paths output by grep, and pasting them after a command that opens a visual editor.

Is there a way of programming a terminal emulator to open selected text in a specific editor?  Perhaps a middle-click on selected text, or an addition to the context menu?

Is this perhaps a feature of some terminal I don't know?

Comment: Similar idea but not exactly what you are looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/447978/is-there-a-plugin-for-the-terminal-which-allow-to-detect-and-open-files/

Answer (score 2):

Create a script:

```
nano ~/<your_script_folder>/open_selection
```

Include the following code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
selected_text=$(xclip -o)
if [[ "$selected_text" == ~* ]]; then
    file_name=$(readlink -f ${selected_text/\~/$HOME})
else
    file_name="$selected_text"
fi

notify-send "Open selection" "$file_name"
xdg-open "$file_name"
```

<sub>*You can replace `xdg-open` with another command of your choice to open the selection with this program.</sub>

Make the script executable

```
chmod +x ~/<your_script_folder>/open_selection
```

Create a shortcut for this script.

Then only select a file name in your terminal and use your shortcut. A detour via the clipboard is not required.

Comment: That's very neat, thanks - but I really want a button to open a file in my editor of choice (sublime, but don't think that is important, just that I get to choose rather than rely upon file-associations/xclip).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do as an alternative is to parse output of `grep` as an argument to your text editor of choice. For instance

`COMMAND | grep -i filename | xargs nano`

In this case nano is just a placeholder. You could use whatever text editor you want there. What you might want to do is to add a `nohup` in front of text editor name, so that you can continue using terminal.

Some time ago I answered a question, [Is it possible to open a terminal in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/a/602238/295286), which asked to "open in terminal". The workaround I've been using is to bind a shortcut to script. You could do something similar - bind a shortcut to simple script bellow:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter path to file")

if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
   nano $FILENAME
fi
```

This basically should bring up a popup asking for path to file.
The path can be copied from command line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, or you can download `xclip` and pipe the output into `xclip -sel clip` (which will put your text path into clipboard)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'm going to have to look at some terminal programs' source code.