# Is there any tool for creating custom right-click-menu entries, that run Python scripts?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, python, text-processing, context-menu

I would like to be able to go anywhere (google chrome, sublime text editor, etc), then highlight + right click on some text, then click a custom right-click-menu button which will run a python script with the highlighted text as input. Is there any tool to do this in Ubuntu 14.04+?

I am aware of Nautilus, however Nautilus right-click commands don't seem to show up on google chrome or sublime text editor, and also I am not aware of any way Nautilus can pass highlighted text as input to a python script.

It would be quite useful to have this capacity, as it would let me automate some tedious aspects of my work-flow, so I wonder if there is a right tool for the job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand well, you have a python script and would like to run it with the selected text asargument? If so, would a shortcut key do?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yeah I guess that could do, I highlight the text, press some shortcut key, and that runs a python script with the selected text as argument. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Absolutely, I have to run, but will post later today if noone did :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Awesome! I would appreciate that a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminal : open path with middle-click/context menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/609540/terminal-open-path-with-middle-click-context-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Another usage of xclip

The solution below uses `xclip`. `xclip` is not on your system by default, you will have to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

In its simplest form, you could do it in a very short script with the help of `xclip`. When we use the `xclip -o` command, the currently selected text is used to output, or as `man xclip` mentions:

```
   -o, -out
          print the selection to standard out (generally for piping to a
          file or program)
```

Using this, we can easily use the selected text to do anything, e.g.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# get the currently selected text
text=$(xclip -o)
# print the selection into a file in your home directory
echo $text > ~/xclip_output.txt
# opening a file with the selected text as a title, in the current working directory
gedit "$text"
```

or, in your case:

```bsh
<script> "$text"
```

If this *exactly* matches what you need depends on what you are actually doing with the input text. Possibly you would have to decide what to do with spaces, (single/double) quotes etc, but this is basically "how it can be done".

#### Adding it to a shortcut key

If you save the script above as `use_text.sh`, you can simply add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
/bin/bash /path/to/use_text.sh
```

to a key combination of your preference

See also: [man xclip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip)

Comment: Why this: `echo $text > ~/xclip_output.txt` :)

Comment: @A.B. Just a silly example. It was my first test line. I left it as an example :)

Comment: Brilliant, that worked pretty smoothly!